# How to create confirm dialog in jqGrid for restoreRow (inline edit mode) when clicking on another row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

It means, when user was editing row in inlineedit mode and then click to another row, it should ask if he wants to save changes or not.
I try to call dialog box like this

```
onSelectRow:function(){ 
$("#confirmsave").dialog('open'); }
```

but because of asynchronous code execution the restoreRow method is called immediately and doesn't wait for response from dialog box.
And one strange thing: if I write

```
onSelectRow: function(){
$("#list").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel);}
```

It still calls restoreRow instead of saveRow as I'm expecting.
Variable lastsel is assigned in oneditfunc and is getting properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem with help of undocumented option `restoreAfterSelect: false` for `inlineNav`.
In this case I can implement custom functions in `onSelectRow` option of grid (for example save row instead of restore, or call callbacks from dialog box). The solution was found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11022542/3590644). Respect for Oleg - master of jqGrid.