# Prevent save on enter key press

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid in my page and now I want to prevent submitting it when enter key is pressed form an editable column. Here is my code.

```
$( '#mygrid' ).jqGrid( {

                 url: '/Mycontroller/LoadMygrid',
                 postData: { 
                    bank_ID: function () { return $( '#bank_accountHead_ID' ).val() },

                },
                //type of data 
                datatype: 'json',
                //url access method type
                mtype: 'POST',
                editurl: 'clientArray',

                colNames: ['chkbox', 'Sl.#', 'amount'],
                //columns model
                colModel: [
                             { name: 'chkSelect', index: 'chkSelect', align: "center", editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', width: '20px', editoptions: { value:                                                                          "True:False" },
                                 fixed: true, formatoptions: { disabled: false}
                             },
                             { name: 'Sl_No', index: 'Sl_No', align: 'left'},

                             { name: 'TotalAmt', index: 'TotalAmt', align: 'right', editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
                           ]
              ..................

                 });
```

I tried setting keys:false in colmodel. Not working. Any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use inline editing close to the form described in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15684127/315935). I posed [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jgrid-inlineedit-be-changed-by-restorerow/#p28552). The **UPDATED** part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684937/315935) describes the problem more detailed. I recommend you to verify whether your problem will be fixed if you would used fixed version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` which you can download [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-restoreRow.js).